# ImportXML Google sheets not helping with extraction from an XML document

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract a couple of elements using the =importXML function in Google sheets from this source: `https://www.ibm.com/homepage_sitemap.xml`

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.ibm.com/homepage_sitemap.xml","//url[*]/loc")
```

It is throwing me a N/A error. Below picture is what I would like to extract. Also, href= against each hreflang value but I am stuck at the first extraction.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.ibm.com/homepage_sitemap.xml","//*[local-name() ='url']/*[local-name() ='loc']")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Absolutely what i was looking for. What would you suggest to extract the href= under each hreflang cluster down. I tried this function but didn't help:

=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name() ='url']/*[local-name() ='xhtml:link']")
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[local-name() ='xhtml:link']/*[local-name() ='href']")

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://www.ibm.com/homepage_sitemap.xml")
```

and to get url:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(REGEXEXTRACT(
 IMPORTDATA("https://www.ibm.com/homepage_sitemap.xml"), 
 "(http.+/)"""), "where Col1 <> '#N/A'"))
```

[image]